# Обработка отдельных кадров из видеопотока OpenCV python

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract

Писал Python код для распознавания текста из получаемого с ip-камеры видеопотока.
В принципе код работает нормально и без ошибок, но производительность очень сильно проседает.
Думаю скорость работы можно ускорить если обрабатывать не весь видео поток а только отдельные кадры через какой-либо временной промежуток.
Как сделать так чтобы через какое-то время скрипт анализировал какой-то отдельный кадр ?

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
import time

# подключаем IP-камеру
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('http://192.168.43.1:4747/video?640x480')

# счётчик FPS
def set_FPS():
    pTime = 0
    cTime = time.time()
    fps = 1 / (cTime - pTime)
    pTime = cTime
    cv2.putText(img, "FPS:" + str(round(fps)), (10, 40), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 255), 1)

# если камера подключена выводим картинку
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        img = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        config = r'--oem 3 --psm 6'
        data = pytesseract.image_to_data(img, config=config)

        ret, frame = cap.read()

        set_FPS()

        for i, el in enumerate(data.splitlines()):
            if i == 0:
                continue
            el = el.split()
            try:
                # создаем подписи на картинке
                x, y, w, h = int(el[6]), int(el[7]), int(el[8]), int(el[9])
                cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (w + x, h + y), (0, 0, 255), 1)
                cv2.putText(img, el[11], (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 255), 1)

            except IndexError:
                print("Операция была пропущена")
            cv2.imshow('Result', img)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Поставить таймер и игнорить фрэймы пока он не истечет